# Android- Fragment appearing behind ImageView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I have an ImageView in an activity, When you click on a part of the image the fragment is updated and is made visible. This works as required, however the fragment is appearing behind the imageView. So I cannot see it. I wish for the fragment to appear in the bottom third of the view. Can anyone suggest why this is happening?

.xml file

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/limerickMapImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:src="@drawable/limerickmap" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/centreButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/centre"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/linkBlue" />



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/infoFragmentLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
     >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/infoFragment"
        class="com.codingwithmitch.googlemaps2018.ui.LocationInfoFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the snippet from my onCreate from the activity where I make the fragment visible

```
  photoview2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            touchX = (int) event.getX();
            touchY = (int) event.getY();
            LocationInfoFragment fragobject2 = (LocationInfoFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.infoFragment) ;
            LinearLayout infoFragementLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.infoFragmentLayout);
            //LinearLayout infoFragementLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.infoFragmentLayout);
            infoFragementLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            for (InfoLocationInformation locationArrayVariable : mInfoLocationInformations) {
                if(touchX > locationArrayVariable.getXy().get(0) & touchX < locationArrayVariable.getXy().get(2) & touchY > locationArrayVariable.getXy().get(1) & touchY < locationArrayVariable.getXy().get(3)){
                    //Log.e(TAG, "Location information for " +  locationArrayVariable.getName()  );


                    if(locationArrayVariable.getType()<1 && infoButton.getBackgroundTintList().getDefaultColor()==-49023+100){

                        bundleString = locationArrayVariable.getText();

                        fragobject2.updateFragment(bundleString);
                        infoFragementLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else if(locationArrayVariable.getType()>0 && locationArrayVariable.getType()<3 && (barButton.getBackgroundTintList().getDefaultColor()==-524991+100 || restaurentButton.getBackgroundTintList().getDefaultColor()==-10879633+100)){
                        bundleString =locationArrayVariable.getText();

                        fragobject2.updateFragment(bundleString);
                        infoFragementLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else if(locationArrayVariable.getType()>2 && locationArrayVariable.getType()<5 && (cafeButton.getBackgroundTintList().getDefaultColor()==-31949+100 || restaurentButton.getBackgroundTintList().getDefaultColor()==-10879633+100)){

                        fragobject2.updateFragment(bundleString);
                        infoFragementLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else if(locationArrayVariable.getType()>4 && cafeButton.getBackgroundTintList().getDefaultColor()==-31949+100){

                        fragobject2.updateFragment(bundleString);
                        infoFragementLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }


                }
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "touch coordinates X" + touchX +" Y "+ touchY  );
            ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
            view.bringToFront();
            viewTransformation(view, event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I have this motion event function which allows me to zoom in and out and move around the imageview in the activity.

```
    private void viewTransformation(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            centreCheck =false;
            xCoOrdinate = view.getX() - event.getRawX();
            yCoOrdinate = view.getY() - event.getRawY();

            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            isOutSide = false;
            mode = DRAG;
            lastEvent = null;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            centreCheck =false;
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }

            lastEvent = new float[4];
            lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
            lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
            lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
            lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
            d = rotation(event);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            centreCheck =false;
            isZoomAndRotate = false;
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
            }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
            centreCheck =false;
            isOutSide = true;
            mode = NONE;
            lastEvent = null;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            centreCheck =false;
            mode = NONE;
            lastEvent = null;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            centreCheck =false;
            if (!isOutSide) {
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    isZoomAndRotate = false;
                    view.animate().x(event.getRawX() + xCoOrdinate).y(event.getRawY() + yCoOrdinate).setDuration(0).start();
                }
                if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                    float newDist1 = spacing(event);
                    if (newDist1 > 10f) {
                        float scale = newDist1 / oldDist * view.getScaleX();
                        view.setScaleX(scale);
                        view.setScaleY(scale);
                    }
                    if (lastEvent != null) {
                        newRot = rotation(event);
                        view.setRotation((float) (view.getRotation() + (newRot - d)));
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your requirement you should go for **BottomSheetFragment** , that will be perfect solution for your requirement.

Check following link

https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/

Comment: This is quite nice, but it still defaults to behind my imageview

Comment: can you share snap?

Comment: I don't have that privilege,  I simply cannot see the fragment/Bottomsheet because the imageview blocks it. I believe raj in the other answer is on the right track. it may be because I have a click listener on the image view.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can Overcome this In the main coordinate view set its background color as white and make it clickable

Comment: main coordinate view? is this my activity layout file?

Comment: whichever xml is coming on top make it clickable nad set background as white as #fff